# URL Rewrite help

Tags: url-rewriting, iis8

Is there any way to forward the following? If I do just the:

```
https://mywebsite.blah.com
```

it gives me this error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

And while I know that this might be a permission problem with my website directory, I have already given NETWORK SERVICES and IIS_IURS access so I am now resorting to this since I know that this works: https://mywebsite.blah.com/this

I think URL Rewrite in IIS can do this with patter matching and I think I stumbled upon the article on how to do http to https redirects earlier but I can't find it again (since it would help me to look at it and figure out how to do it)

I would like to redirect from:

```
https://mywebsite.blah.com
```

To:

```
https://mywebsite.blah.com/this
```

Comment: This error appears when directory listing is disabled and there is no default file found. Check to see if you have index.html, or index.htm, or index,asp, or index.php and that there is a setting that allows the file to be a default file where none is specified.

Comment: How do you set one to be a default and how do enable directory listing?

There is a Default.aspx and a Web.config

Comment: I do not know IIS anymore. It has been well over a decade for me. But that message indicates that a default file is not found for some reason. It could also be that the trailing slash mywebsite.blah.com/ is not added which should be normal. Try adding a trailing slash to know for sure.

Comment: No, it isn't the trailing slash :(